# Error with skipping the first line of a file

Tags: python

With the command `next(a_file)`, I can skip the first line of a file **but only if there is actually a line**. If there is nothing in the file at the time of the command I get an error. How can I avoid this problem?

Example for error:

```
a_file = open("helloo.txt") 
next(a_file) 
print(a_file.read())
```

Comment: Could you share the contents of the file as well.

Comment: What would you like to happen if there is no line in the file?

Comment: Also what is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `try: except` block. You want to catch only the `StopIteration` exception, so that any other (`FileNotFoundError`,...) doesn't get caught here:

```
a_file = open("helloo.txt") 
try:
    next(a_file)
except StopIteration:
    print("Empty file")
    # or just
    #pass

print(a_file.read())
```

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap it with a try except block:

```
try:
    next(a_file)
except StopIteration:
    # handle the exception
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make use of `try`-`except` block in python in order to detect if there is any error occurring while calling the `next()` method. In case any error occurs, which in your case will be **`StopIteration`**, we execute the except block and thus the program continues smoothly.

```
a_file = open("helloo.txt") 

try:
    next(a_file) 
except StopIteration:
    print("File is empty.")
    
print(a_file.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the file is empty and if not, do `next()`:

```
import os

a_file = open("helloo.txt")
if os.stat("helloo.txt").st_size != 0:
    next(a_file) 
print(a_file.read())
a_file.close()
```

Or you can use `try` `except` like this:

```
a_file = open("helloo.txt") 
try:
    next(a_file)
except StopIteration:
    pass

print(a_file.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad practice to assign a `open` call to a variable via the `=` operator. Instead, use `with`:

```
with open("usernames.txt") as a_file:
    try:
        next(a_file)
        print(a_file.read())
    except StopIteration:
        print("Empty")
```

I'd also like to introduce you to the [`finally`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#finally) statement; it only comes after both `try` and `except` are used in a block:

```
with open("usernames.txt") as a_file:
    try:
        next(a_file)
        print(a_file.read())
    except StopIteration:
        print("Empty")
    finally:
        print("End!")
```